# Find Memcache port number when started with homebrew as a service

Tags: memcached, homebrew

I installed homebrew and then memcache through it and started it as a service.I am unable to find on which port it is running though.When I do a ps -ef|grep memcached it does not give me any results.But it is definately running because I could see it listening to socket when I do memcached -vv.

Could anybody help? How can I find out the port number on which it is running?

Answer (score 4):

Homebrew does not specify a port; memcached's default port is 11211. You can use `lsof -i` to see what processes have open sockets on OS X.